# How can I verify a class method is called using XCTAssert?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, tdd, xctestcase

I have a service class, I would like to assert 2 things

1. A method is called
2. The correct params are passed to that method

Here is my class

```
protocol OAuthServiceProtocol {
    func initAuthCodeFlow() -> Void
     func renderOAuthWebView(forService service: IdentityEndpoint, queryitems: [String: String]) -> Void
}

class OAuthService: OAuthServiceProtocol {

    fileprivate let apiClient: APIClient

    init(apiClient: APIClient) {
        self.apiClient = apiClient
    }

    func initAuthCodeFlow() -> Void {

    }

    func renderOAuthWebView(forService service: IdentityEndpoint, queryitems: [String: String]) -> Void {

    }
}
```

Here are my tests

```
class OAuthServiceTests: XCTestCase {
    var mockAPIClient: APIClient!
    var mockURLSession: MockURLSession!
    var sut: OAuthService!

    override func setUp() {
        mockAPIClient = APIClient()
        mockAPIClient.session = MockURLSession(data: nil, urlResponse: nil, error: nil)
        sut = OAuthService(apiClient: mockAPIClient)
    }

    func test_InitAuthCodeFlow_CallsRenderOAuthWebView() {
        let renderOAuthWebViewExpectation = expectation(description: "RenderOAuthWebView")

        class OAuthServiceMock: OAuthService {
            override func initAuthCodeFlow() -> Void {

            }

            override func renderOAuthWebView(forService service: IdentityEndpoint, queryitems: [String: String]) {
                renderOAuthWebViewExpectation.fulfill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping to create a local sub class of OAuthService, assign that as my `sut` and call something like like `sut.initAuthCodeFlow()` and then assert that my expectation was fulfilled.

I believe this should satisfy point 1. However I cannot access my expectation when attempting to assign it as fulfilled as I get the following error

> Class declaration cannot close over value
>   'renderOAuthWebViewExpectation' defined in outer scope

How can I mark this as fulfilled?

I am following a TDD approach, so I understand my OAuthService would produce a failing test at this point anyway*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a property on your mock, mutating it's value within the method you expect to call. You can then use your XCTAssertEqual to check that prop has been updated.

```
   func test_InitAuthCodeFlow_CallsRenderOAuthWebView() {
        let renderOAuthWebViewExpectation = expectation(description: "RenderOAuthWebView")

        class OAuthServiceMock: OAuthService {
            var renderOAuthWebViewExpectation: XCTestExpectation!
            var didCallRenderOAuthWebView = false

            override func renderOAuthWebView(forService service: IdentityEndpoint, queryitems: [String: String]) {
                didCallRenderOAuthWebView = true
                renderOAuthWebViewExpectation.fulfill()
            }
        }

        let sut = OAuthServiceMock(apiClient: mockAPIClient)

        XCTAssertEqual(sut.didCallRenderOAuthWebView, false)
        sut.renderOAuthWebViewExpectation = renderOAuthWebViewExpectation

        sut.initAuthCodeFlow()
        waitForExpectations(timeout: 1) { _ in
            XCTAssertEqual(sut.didCallRenderOAuthWebView, true)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

> I was hoping to create a local sub class of `OAuthService`, assign that as my sut and call something like like `sut.initAuthCodeFlow()` and then assert that my expectation was fulfilled.

I would strongly discourage you from using this approach. If your SUT is an instance of the subclass then your test is not truly testing `OAuthService`, but `OAuthService` mock.

Moreover, if we think of tests as a tool to:

- prevent bugs when code is change
- help refactoring and maintenance of the code

then I would argue that testing that calling a certain function calls another function is not a good test. That's harsh, I know, so let me unpack why that's the case.

The only thing it's testing is that `initAuthCodeFlow()` calls `renderOAuthWebView(forService:, queryitems:)` under the hood. It doesn't have any assertion on the actual *behaviour* of the system under test, on the outputs it produces directly or not. If I were to edit the implementation of `renderOAuthWebView(forService:, queryitems:)` and add some code that would crash at runtime this test would not fail.

A test like this doesn't help with keeping the codebase easy to change, because if you want to change the implementation of `OAuthService`, maybe by adding a parameter to `renderOAuthWebView(forService:, queryitems:)` or by renaming `queryitems` into `queryItems` to match the capitalization, you'll have to update both the production code and the test. In other words, the test will get in your way of refactoring -changing how the code looks without changing how it behaves- without any extra benefit.

So, how should one test `OAuthService` in a way that prevents bugs and helps moving fast? The trick is all in testing the behaviour instead of the implementation.

What should `OAuthService` *do*? `initAuthCodeFlow()` doesn't return any value, so we can check for direct outputs, but we can still check indirect outputs, side effects.

I'm making a guess here, but I from your test checking that `renderOAuthWebView(forService:, queryitems:)` I'd and the fact that it gets an `APIClient` type as input I'd say it'll present some kind of web view for a certain URL, and then make another request to the given `APIClient` maybe with the OAuth token received from the web view?

A way to test the interaction with `APIClient` is to make an assertion for the expected endpoint to be called. You can do it with a tool like [OHHTTPStubs](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs) or with your a custom test double for `URLSession` that records the requests it gets and allows you to check them.

As for the presentation of the web view, you can use the delegate patter for it, and set a test double conforming to the delegate protocol which records whether it's called or not. Or you could test at a higher level and inspect the `UIWindow` in which the test are running to see if the root view controller is the one with the web view.

At the end of the day is all a matter of trade offs. The approach you've taken is not wrong, it just optimizes more towards asserting the code implementation rather than its behaviour. I hope that with this answer I showed a different kind of optimization, one biased towards the behaviour. In my experience this style of testing proves more helpful in the medium-long run.